# Solve the cauchy problem and check the solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider $$xU_x +y U_y = 0$$

$$U(x,y) = x, \ \ \ \ on \ \  \ \ x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

has

1. a solution for all x,y $\in \mathbb R$
2. an unique solution in $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : (x,y) \neq 0 \}$
3. a bounded solution in $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : (x,y) \neq 0 \}$
4. an unique solution in $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : (x,y) \neq 0 \}$, but the solution is unbounded.

We can solve this by Lagranges method, we obtain $U(x,y = f(x-y)$ for some function $f$

We have given that $U(x,y) = x, \ \ \ \ on \ \  \ \ x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so $U(cos(\theta), sin(\theta)) = cos(\theta)$ for all $\theta$.

Please help me check which option is true.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Our starting point is
\begin{equation*}
(x\partial _{x}+y\partial _{y})U(x,y)=0
\end{equation*}
But
\begin{equation*}
x\partial _{x}+y\partial _{y}=r\partial _{r},\;r=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
r\partial _{r}U(r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta ) &=&0 \\
\partial _{r}U(r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta ) &=&0,\;r\neq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
and, since
\begin{equation*}
U(\cos \theta ,\sin \theta )=\cos \theta
\end{equation*}
we obtain
\begin{equation*}
U(r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta )=U(\cos \theta ,\sin \theta )=\cos \theta
\end{equation*}

Comment: Urgie: how to check these option whether it is true or not

Comment: Do you mean the last line? U(rcosθ,rsinθ)-U(cosθ,sinθ)=∫ds(∂_s)U(scosθ,ssinθ)=0 where the integral is from r to 1.

Comment: Should be from 1 to r